# Anti-trace applied on the trace zero subgroup and distortion maps

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I was reading [*Pairings for Beginners*](http://www.craigcostello.com.au/pairings/PairingsForBeginners.pdf) by Craig Costello and he talks about the base field subgroup $\mathcal{G}_1 =  E[r] \cap \ker(\pi - 1)$ and the trace zero subgroup $\mathcal{G}_2 =  E[r] \cap \ker(\pi - q)$. He then defines the $Tr$ map and $aTr$ map on the entire $r$-torsion. See section 4.1 regarding the $r$-torsion.

I understood that $Tr$ moves everything in $r$-torsion in $\mathcal{G}_1$ except for $\mathcal{G}_2$ which sends the elements there into $\mathcal{O}$ (which is also in $\mathcal{G}_1$). Also $aTr$ sends "everything" from $r$-torsion into $\mathcal{G}_2$.

**First question:** Does $aTr$ sends also $\mathcal{G}_1$ into $\mathcal{G}_2$ or only in $\mathcal{O}$ ? I am asking because $Tr$ does not send $\mathcal{G}_2$ into entire $\mathcal{G}_1$ but only in $\mathcal{O}$.

Also, he talks about distortion maps and searching on google it seems that a distortion map is defined as a monomorphism
$$\phi : {\mathcal{G}_1} \longrightarrow E[r] \setminus {\mathcal{G}_1}$$
But the *Pairings for Beginners* does not define the distortion map at all, even more it allows that the distortion map to be defined over subgroups other than $\mathcal{G}_1$ (see Figure 4.5, 4.6), so here is my second question.

**Second question:** It seems that distorsion map when is defined over $\mathcal{G}_2$ moves the elements out of $\mathcal{G}_2$ also. Is it true ?

Also, regarding distortion maps, I come with the third question.

**Third question:** It seems that $\mathcal{O}$ could be mapped via the distorsion map out of the torsion. Is this desired in general or should be avoided ?